# Endless Oracle update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

With SQL Developer on a 11g database, I'm trying to update a record, like this :

```
update table_test
set field_test = 0
where table_test_id = 64664;
```

The problem is that query is taking very very long. 8 minutes have elapsed without success.

Has anyone an idea about what could be wrong ?

Comment: Does it take along time to do a `SELECT field_test` with the same `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Are there 20 billion records with `table_test_id = 64664`? :P

Comment: There are only one record associated with this WHERE clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Is `TABLE_TEST_ID` the primary key of the table?
- Are there triggers on the table?
- Is it possible that some other session has locked this particular row and you're simply waiting on that lock?  Do you see anything in the `DBA_WAITERS` and `DBA_BLOCKERS` tables?

Comment: TABLE_TEST_ID is indeed the primary key of the table.

Comment: There is a trigger on the "INSERT" event.

Comment: The two following tables show nothing :
SELECT * FROM DBA_WAITERS;
SELECT * FROM DBA_BLOCKERS;

But for now, I observes that the update now works.
I presume that your observation was right and the lock has been timed out now. I remember that I recently used a program that crashed one one update at this record, so... ok !

Answer (score 7):

Probably the record you are trying to update is locked by another session - quite possibly another session of yours?  This session will be blocked, and will wait until the other session commits or rolls back its transaction.

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds.  I need to improve my typing speed.

Comment: It was actually 1 minute and 12 seconds. Hover the "answered" time to see the actual timestamps.